# Is it necessary to dispatch to main queue in HealthKit when consecutively deleting then saving an HKWorkout?

Tags: ios, swift, grand-central-dispatch, watchos

My code below is on the watch and is taking an existing HKWorkout, modifying a value in it, and re-saving it.  To do this I need to make a copy and delete the old.  Do I need to dispatch to the main queue prior to my `save` call nested in the `delete` call?  Or is if sufficient that I dispatch to the main queue prior to any UI calls?  I've noticed some strange behaviour with the UI on the watch that I thought might be thread related? See the line I marked below:

```
 healthStoreManager.deleteWorkout(workout: workoutSavedWithoutStatsUnwrapped) { (successDeleting, error) in

                    if let unwrappedError = error {
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            let action2 = WKAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: {

                                WKInterfaceController.reloadRootPageControllers(withNames: ["InterfaceController"],
                                                                                contexts: nil,
                                                                                orientation: .vertical,
                                                                                pageIndex: 0)
                                print("Error Saving workout")
                            })
                            WKInterfaceDevice.current().play(.failure)
                            self.presentAlert(withTitle: "Add Stats Error", message: "We were not able to add stats to your workout at this time, please enter them on the iPhone. Error: \(unwrappedError)", preferredStyle: .alert, actions: [action2])
                        }
                    }

                    if successDeleting == true {

******DO I NEED TO `DispatchQueue.main.async {` here? ********


                        self.healthStoreManager.saveWorkoutWithMetaData(session: self.workoutSession, workoutStartDate: self.startDate) { (successSaving, error) in

                            if let unwrappedError = error {
                                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                    let action2 = WKAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: {
                                        print("Error Saving workout")
                                    })
                                    WKInterfaceDevice.current().play(.failure)
                                    self.presentAlert(withTitle: "Save Error", message: "We were not able to add stats to your workout at this time, please enter them on the iPhone. Error: \(unwrappedError)", preferredStyle: .alert, actions: [action2])
                                }
                            }

                            if successSaving == true {
                                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                    WKInterfaceDevice.current().play(.success)
                                    self.showSuccessAlertWith(message: "Workout Saved, Stats Added.")
                                }
                            } else {
                                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                    let action2 = WKAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: {
                                        print("Error Saving workout")
                                        WKInterfaceController.reloadRootPageControllers(withNames: ["InterfaceController"],
                                                                                        contexts: nil,
                                                                                        orientation: .vertical,
                                                                                        pageIndex: 0)
                                    })
                                    WKInterfaceDevice.current().play(.failure)
                                    self.presentAlert(withTitle: "Save Error", message: "We were not able to add stats to your workout at this time, please enter them on the iPhone.", preferredStyle: .alert, actions: [action2])
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Comment: All that I could find in the documentation is "This method operates **asynchronously**. As soon as the save operation is finished, it calls the completion block on a background queue." This may suggest that the block should get executed on the main thread. But it's not really definitive.

Comment: @Sam thanks I know that both the delete and save calls were async, so my question is more generally do I need to: (1) async block call (2) async block call (3) dispatch main queue and update UI or do I need to (1) async block call (2) dispatch main queue (3) async block call  (4) dispatch main queue and update UI?  It sounds like the latter?

Comment: If dispatching to the main queue solves your problem, then that is what must have gone wrong. But in general whenever I don't see the docs specifying to use a certain queue, all of the threading is already handled by the implementation of that method.